# Ошибка ssl при подключении к базе данных mysql средствами jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc, mysqlconnector

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/logiccompany";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,"root","1997");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

выдает ошибку:

> Wed Nov 08 23:04:37 EET 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

Версия MySQL 5.7.17.
MySQL - connector 5.1.44 -bin.jar

Answer (score 1):

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

В конец url добавьте `?useSSL=false`, а так то все было сказано в сообщении ошибки

Answer (score 1):

Строка подключения URL должна выглядеть следующим образом:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/logiccompany?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

Это отключит SSL, заодно перестанет выдавать ошибки SSL.

---

<sup>При формировании ответа использовался [ответ на вопрос «Warning about SSL connection when connecting to MySQL database»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34449182/11141611) от участника [@priyank-gosalia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4365949/priyank-gosalia).</sup>